# How do I make the black line smaller on an EditText in an AlertDialog?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-alertdialog

[This is the alertdialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAl6K.png)

I am using a custom xml file for the EditText to change its appearance. I have tried settings layout margins, padding, and setting it to custom widths but nothing changes the line.

This is the editText's xml:

```
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/myEditTextId"
android:layout_width="300dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/dark_cursor"
tools:ignore="Autofill,LabelFor" />
```

Comment: Show the .xml file so that I can solve your problem.

Comment: I've updated the question with the xml

Answer (score 0):

Try to create custom drawable and set it as background for the EditText

Like:

**drawable/custom_bg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:thickness="2dp"
   android:shape="rectangle">
  <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#000000"/>
```

```
<EditText android:background="@drawable/custom_bg"/>
```

Comment: that actually made the black line disappear, but yknow I kinda like the look of it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution that will make your UI more flexible. First make your `Edittext`'s `background="@null"`. Then make a black underline for your `Edittext`. Here you can increase or decrease the thickness of black line by increasing or decreasing it's height value which is currently `2px`. You can make it shorter or longer by increasing or decreasing it's start and end margin. You can also resize your `EditText`. Everything you can do now with margin, padding, custom height, custom width etc.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:hint="Your textview"/>
    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider1"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2px"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @whiskey Let me know if it is fulfilling your need properly or not?

Comment: I am programmatically declaring my edit text and using LayoutInflater to inflate the edittext xml in the dialog so unfortunately the linear layout cannot be inflated into an EditText variable

Comment: @whisKey Instead of inflating the `EditText` programmatically place my code into your `xml` file and you can hide or show it using `android:visibility="visible"` or `android:visibility="gone"`.